# C++ DXUT Build/Usage

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I´m trying to build a Game with DirectX 11 on Windows 7.

I have downloaded the DX-SDK June 2010 and build a DXUT.lib from the code in Samples/C++/DXUT11/Core.

When using any DXUT-Function the linker throws the error:
`LNK2001: unresolved extern symbol "_D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW@20"`

The way i´m linking the lib is:
 `#pragma comment (lib, "DXUT.lib")`

Also i´m including the DXUT.h from the DX SDK folder.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link d3dx9.lib, and include D3dx9tex.h, please see the MSDN page for function [D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks to you this solved my problem :)
But now i get an error message "Failed creating the Direct3D device." I´m using: 
`DXUTInit(true, true, lpCmdLine, true);
DXUTCreateWindow(L"Test", hInstance);
DXUTCreateDevice(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, true, 300, 300);
`
The last line is where the error occures...
Any idea why this action fails?

Comment: You should check the return value of DXUTCreateDevice.

Comment: The HRESULT says 0x80040905.
But i don´t think it´s an valid errorcode